# Extract information from a Transport Stream in Java

Tags: java, mpeg2-ts, transport-stream

I need to extract some information from a Transport Stream like PID, PAT, PMT, etc.

I found an example code to get the PID:

```
pid = ((buf[1] << 8) | (buf[2] & 0xff)) & 0x1fff;
```

But I could not understand the reason to get the `buf[1]` and shift 8 to the left side because to get the PID information I need get the 5 last bits from the `buf[1]` and all 8 from the `buf[2]`. I tested the code and the result was good. I just want to understand the mean of this first part: `buf[1] << 8` in the equation. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PID is 13 bits long.

The buffer `buf` is a `byte` array. Each element is 8 bits.

The smallest Java integer type to hold a PID is the `short` (16-bit signed integer). `buf[1] << 8` promotes the `byte` to an `int` (4 bytes) while shifting so you now have enough space to hold the result.

```
  buf[1] = XXXXXXXX
  buf[2] = YYYYYYYY

  buf[1] << 8 
  shifted 8 positions to the left in a 32-bit int

  0                   1                   2                   3
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 X X X X X X X X 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0| 
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+


  (buf[1] << 8) | buf[2]

  0                   1                   2                   3
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 X X X X X X X X Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y| 
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+


  ((buf[1] << 8) | buf[2]) & 0x1fff

  0                   1                   2                   3
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 X X X X X Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y| 
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

`buf[2] & 0xff` is needed because in Java all bytes are signed and you need the unsigned `int` value of the byte. Finally the whole thing is masked with `0x1fff` to keep the relevant 13 bits. If you want a `short` you must cast the resulting `int`.

Comment: Thank you @aergistal! Now I got the ideia.

Comment: Do you know any website that I can get more information about bitmasks? Like, I have more information to extract each one with different size of bits but I don't have the masks for each one

Comment: You can see examples for all bitwise operations on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation. `|` is `OR`, `&` is AND and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your PID is 4660 or 0x1234. so `buf[1] = 0x12`, and `buf[2] = 0x34`

Lest do the math `int a = 0x12 | 0x32` what is a set to? `a = 0x36`.

`0x36 != 0x1234`. What we need is `int a = 0x1200 | 0x34` to get `0x1234`

How do we turn `0x12` into `0x1200`? We shift it left by 8 bits. `(buf[1] << 8)`